# Postfix virtualdomains and relays of some domains

Tags: postfix, dovecot, arch-linux

I have an ArchLinux server with postfix, postfixadmin, dovecot, roundcube, quotas and spamassassin running fine.

The server is the main (not a backup or forwarding) of 3 virtual domains: `domone.example`, `domtwo.example`, and `domthree.example`.

The server is running perfectly, has no problems and is in production. All three domains can send and receive mail from and to the outside, and between them.

Now I need to change it so that nothing changes for `domone.example` and `domtwo.example` but `domthree.example` should now behave like this:

- `domthree.example` can receive mails from outside and from `domone.example`, `domtwo.example` and `domthree.example`.
- `domthree.example` can send mail only to `domone.example`, `domtwo.example` and `domthree.example`, but not to the outside or other domains.

I have been searching for 3 days, I know it is related to `relay_domains` and `virtual_domains`, but I can not find the solution.

Comment: This sounds like it would be best implemented with a [policy server](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html). So you would add "check_policy_service (server_address)" to smtpd_recipient_restrictions. And your policy server would return  "action=OK" unless "sender=*@domthree.example" in which case it would return "action=REJECT" unless "recipient=*@domone.example | *@domtwo.example | *@domthree.example"

Comment: I try this way:
1- Put "smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/dominios_virtuales_access.cf" into main.cf
2- /etc/postfix/dominios_virtuales_access.cf:
domthree.com.ar REJECT
.domthree.com.ar REJECT
domtwo.com.ar OK  
.domtwo.com.ar OK
domone.com.ar OK
.domone.com.ar OK

The result is that donone and domtwo works as espected, but domthree can't send any mail. No to external (GOOD) and not to domone or domtwo (BAD)

Thank you

Comment: @cburn11:  I going to try that way. Thank you!